# Can an abandoned software project "gather dust"?

Tags: idioms, figurative

I was reading [a blog](http://fpgb.org/) of someone who is trying to emulate Nintendo Gameboy hard- and software as a hobby project. In the oldest post, in the following sentence:

> I eventually [...] bought myself a flash cardridge [...]  to make a few little test programs which are still gathering dust on an old HDD somewhere.

the author says that old software he wrote is *gathering dust* on a [Hard Disk Drive].

The meaning of this idiom is that something remains untouched for a certain amount of time, but I'm not sure whether this can be used if it doesn't apply literally, which it always seems to do. You can leave any *object* sitting unused somewhere and it will gather dust in the physical world.

Computer programs are digital, they have no relation to the physical world, as of such they cannot literally gather dust. Is the quoted sentence linguistically correct? If so, does that mean this idiom can be used for anything non-physical?

Comment: An idiom, by definition, can be used figuratively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The meaning of the term "gathering dust" has been extended through daily usage, particularly in the digital age, to include items that cannot literally gather dust such as digital items. It means, as you surmised, that it has been untouched for an extended amount of time.